# Oracle, What is the Meaning of Table SYS.SYN$?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

**In Oracle DB, what is the table SYS.SYN$ used for?** The doc (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/timesten.1122/e21644/systemtables.htm#TTSYS347) states only that it is reserved for internal use.

The doc (http://psoug.org/reference/synonyms.html) lists it as something related to synonymes but does not explain its role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an internal part of the data dictionary, parts of which are exposed by views or used in packages. In 11gR2 those are:

```
select type, owner, name from dba_dependencies
where referenced_owner = 'SYS' and referenced_name = 'SYN$'
order by type, owner, name;

TYPE               OWNER                          NAME                         
------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
PACKAGE BODY       SYS                            DBMS_SNAPSHOT_UTL             
PACKAGE BODY       SYS                            RMJVM                         
VIEW               SYS                            ALL_SYNONYMS                  
VIEW               SYS                            DBA_SYNONYMS                  
VIEW               SYS                            DICTIONARY                    
VIEW               SYS                            DICT_COLUMNS                  
VIEW               SYS                            EXU8SYN                       
VIEW               SYS                            EXU9PTS                       
VIEW               SYS                            EXU9SYN                       
VIEW               SYS                            EXU9UTS                       
VIEW               SYS                            IMP9SYN4                      
VIEW               SYS                            KU$_SYNONYM_VIEW              
VIEW               SYS                            KU$_SYN_EXISTS_VIEW           
VIEW               SYS                            SYNONYMS                      
VIEW               SYS                            USER_SYNONYMS                 
VIEW               SYS                            _ALL_SYNONYMS_FOR_AUTH_OBJECTS
VIEW               SYS                            _ALL_SYNONYMS_FOR_SYNONYMS
```

From the view definitions you can see, for example, that `dba_synonyms` joins that to `sys.user$` and `sys._current_edition_obj` to get readable and useful information out.

There is no reason to refer to it directly, and like any part data dictionary (or anything owned by SYS) you should not even think about changing it or its contents.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to use it explicitely just wanted to know its role but thanks also for this hint.